# how to get rid of duplicates inside a printline

Tags: java

ive been trying to solve this for the last 5 hours and i'm exhausted ..

 i need to build a method that takes an array of numbers and determaines which **right** digit was shown the least times in an thr array. for example if the array is [134,12634,124,5667] the number that will be shown is 7 .. i hope i'm clear enough:(

anyways this is the code. i manged to get to the part where it show the number but it will show it as many times as the loop runs for.

please help

```
public static boolean QuestionD(int[] arr)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int printNum = 0;
        String[] arr2 = new String[arr.length];
        int[] arr3 = new int[arr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            if (arr[i] < 0)
                return false;//if the numbers are negative return false;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++)
        {
            printNum = arr[j] % 10;// get the right digit of the number
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
                    if (arr[i] % 10 == printNum)// if the right digit of the first index matches the other index then counter ++;
                        counter++;// to count how many times the right digit is shown
                arr2[j] = printNum + "" + counter;// to make the number as a string and will be 2 digits , the first digit from the left
                //will be the digit that appears on the right , and the second digit will be the times that the digit appeared
                arr3[j] = Integer.parseInt(arr2[j]);//make it back to an int
                counter = 0;// setting counter back to zero to check the other numbers
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)
                if (arr3[i] % 10 < arr3[j] % 10)
                    System.out.print((arr3[i] / 10 % 10) + " ");// here i take the digits that were shown the less but will duplicates 
            //as many times as the for loop runs for.
        
        }
        
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: You want to get digit with least frequency in the array? Do you think you can do it by maintaining a frequency map and then returning key with lowest frequency?

Comment: You've set up your counter in a very complex way. Maybe you could have an array `counter` of size 10? And when you have a number ending in 7 you increment `counter[7]` ? (That's just a start but I think you can figure out the rest).

Comment: just use an array of ten, everytime you got the right digit increment the index like, counter[(int)digit]++. At the last just use one variable for `least` and loop the counter once while updating the least variable

Comment: @Rohan Kumar i'm at my first year of my degree i havnt learnt maps yet

Comment: @alcatraz can you bring up a solution please . i'm hopeless really haha

Comment: i could place the digits in an array but i dont know how to get rid of the duplicates

Comment: @rajah9 i got mixed up with everything i really dont know how to continue

Comment: Okay, even without a map this problem can be solved with an integer array of size 10. Could you please share some more sample test cases so that we can understand problems better?

Comment: sure, what if the array's size is more than 10? it will be limited and show an error ?

Comment: @alcatraz sounds really complicaited

Comment: @avihu24 Regarding your original solution: at the line with *"to make the number as a string and will be 2 digits"* you invented a system where a string represented some combination of two values. Don't juggle with strings like this. If you want to store two values like that, then create a class with two properties.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think your solution can be much simpler.

If I understand correctly, you want:

- For each number, extract the **rightmost** digit;
- Record the frequency of each digit;
- Show the one occurring the least number of times.

Here's how you could do this. Since the number of options is fairly small – there are only 10 digits – you could simply create an array with size 10, to keep track of the number of all occurrences of each digit<sup>1</sup>.

```java
// First, we'll define an integer array with size 10 with indexes from 0 to
// 9. We can use the indexes to store the frequencies of each of the digits
// from 0 to 9.
int[] frequencies = new int[10];

// Then we collect the frequencies of all numbers. We walk over each element
// of the array
for (int number : numbers) {
    // We use the remainder operator to get the rightmost digit. This
    // guarantees that the result of the operation never exceeds 9.
    int digit = number % 10;

    // We increment the counter for that specific integer
    frequencies[digit]++;
}

// Now we have the frequencies of all digits. Now all we have to do is walk
// over our collected frequencies, and check which one has the lowest
// frequency.

// We initialize the digit and its frequency with -1, which means in our case
// that we have not yet recorded a least frequency.
int leastQuantity = -1;
int leastNumber = -1;

// Now we must check all digits
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // A composite if statement, doing some magic. How it works, see below.
    if (frequencies[i] > 0 && (frequencies[i] < leastQuantity || leastNumber == -1)) {
        leastQuantity = frequencies[i];
        leastNumber = i;
    }
}

System.out.println("The rightmost digit " + leastNumber + " occurs " + leastQuantity + " times");
// Or if you want to list all numbers with the least frequency:
for (int i = 0; i < frequencies.length; i++) {
    if (frequencies[i] == leastQuantity) {
        System.out.println(leastNumber);
    }
}
```

**That `if` statement**:

- `frequencies[i] > 0` — The frequency must be greater than 0. If the frequency of a number is 0, then it doesn't occur at all, that is, it was never a rightmost digit of any number within the array. So we must only count frequencies greater than 0.
- Either of the following must be true:

  - `leastNumber == -1` — Meaning we have not yet recorded a frequency, so if the frequency is greater than 0, we must record it.
  - `frequencies[i] < leastQuantity` — If the current frequency is lower than the last one recorded, update both the number and its frequency.

---

There are some assumptions here:

- `numbers` is not `null`. You may want to write `Objects.requireNonNull(numbers)` as the first statement of the method body, in order to [fast-fail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast).
- `numbers.length > 0`. You may want to write

  ```java
  if (numbers.length == 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Given array has no elements");
  }
  ```
- None of the numbers within `numbers` is negative. If any of the numbers is, then the code tries to write at a negative array index, causing an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown. We could allow negative numbers, but then we must make sure `digit` is absolute:

  ```java
  int digit = Math.abs(number % 10);
  ```

---

<sup>1</sup> There may be digits which never occur as the rightmost digit, leaving unused array positions. In your specific example, that would be all digits except 4 and 7. For small values such as 10, this is entirely fine. However, if you were to extract the *four* rightmost digits and count the frequencies, then you ended up with a very large array, possibly with many unused positions. In such cases, you may be better off using a (`Hash`)`Map` to map a certain number to their frequency. With such a map, it'll no longer contain unused values, instead, it'll contain only numbers where the frequency is greater than 0. See [Rohan Kumar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68285558/507738) for an example.

Comment: i understood what you brought up i think it will fix the problem i'll try it , thanks

Comment: i think it should be `digits[i] != 0 && digits[i] < leastQuantity`, since all index of digits will instantiate with 0, because it's primitive array

Comment: @alcatraz you're right the outputs shows 0

Comment: @alcatraz where should i place this line?

Comment: @alcatraz Good catch. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @MCEmperor theres a problem with your code can you help me fix this ? it shows zero everytime i run it

Comment: do i need to make an array of the variable frequencies?

Comment: @MCEmperor i changed the name of the array digits to frequencies and it still shows 0 ? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: it always zero because the code assume the frequencies[0] as the greatest number, i wont do that, instead i will initiate `leastQuantity` with `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and `leastNumber` with -1, -1 means that's no number (when the numbers is empty array)

Comment: yeah you just updated it while i'm typing haha

Comment: great!!! it works ! , but what if there are values that are the same.. what if there are 2 numbers that the most right digit is shown once ?

Comment: loop once more on the frequencies when you already know the least quantity, `if (frequencies[i] == leastQuantity) System.out.println(i)`

Comment: @avihu24 If this worked for you, please mark this answer as accepted, to let the community know that this question is solved.

Comment: @MCEmperor sure , how do i do that?

Comment: @avihu24 Below the score counter at the left top of this answer, there is a checkmark. If you click it, it'll become green and the answer is marked accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're interested in using Map for storing frequencies instead of an array(You won't need to deal with digits with zero frequencies in this case). You might find this solution helpful. Here I'm just populating frequency map and then getting the entry with minimum value:

```java
private static int getLeastFrequentDigit(int[] array) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> digitFrequencyMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (int j : array) {
        int key = j % 10;
        digitFrequencyMap.merge(key, 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> minEntry = digitFrequencyMap.entrySet().stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparingInt(Map.Entry::getValue))
            .orElse(null);
    return minEntry != null ? minEntry.getKey() : -1;
}
```